# How to run the Haxe server and client example?

Tags: flash, server, client, haxe

I am new to Haxe.

I want to try to run the example from here:

http://old.haxe.org/doc/flash/chat

but I do not know how to run.

I just type

```
haxe app.hxml
```

and I have no idea how to continue.

Could someone tell me how to run it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running `haxe app.hxml` creates two files: `server.n` and `client.swf`.

Double click `server.bat` (which just starts the server via `neko server.n`). Now any number of clients can connect to the server. For testing, just run the `client.hx` twice with the standalone Flash Player. After you've entered a user name in each window, any message you submit on either client will appear on the other client as well.

[image]

Comment: SecurityError: Error #2010: Local-with-filesystem SWF files are not permitted to use sockets.
 at flash.net::Socket/internalConnect()
 at flash.net::Socket/connect()
 at flash.net::XMLSocket/connect()
 at Client()
 at Client$/main()
 at boot_08b8/init()
 at flash::Boot/start()
 at boot_08b8()

Comment: Error #2044: Unhandled securityError:. text=Error #2048: Security sandbox violation: file:///(my local file address)/client.swf cannot load data from localhost:1024.
 at Client()
 at Client$/main()
 at boot_08b8/init()
 at flash::Boot/start()
 at boot_08b8()