# How to send a list of objects in Haxe between client and server?

Tags: client-server, haxe, openfl

I am trying to write an online message board in Haxe (OpenFL). There are lots of server/client examples online. But I am new to this area and I do not understand any of them. What is the easiest way to send a list of objects between server and client? Could you guys give an example?

Comment: Actually, seeing as you have [already](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35071564/how-to-run-the-haxe-server-and-client-example) explored a bit Haxe Remoting with the chat tutorial, I'm not sure what you question is.  At least, remoting (which uses serialization internally) is the already a pretty good way to do it...  Can you give us more details on what are exactly your issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: I'm not still sure if the user's problem is really about sending "a list of objects"; see [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35134560/how-to-send-a-list-of-object-in-haxe-client-server-communication#comment58002900_35134560) to the question...

---

The easiest way is to use [Haxe Serialization](http://haxe.org/manual/std-serialization.html), either with [Haxe Remoting](http://haxe.org/manual/std-remoting-connection.html) or with your own protocol on top of TCP/UDP.  The choice of protocol depends whether you already have something built and whether you will be calling functions or simply getting/posting data.

In either case, `haxe.Serializer/Unserializer` will give you a format to transmit most (if not all) Haxe objects from client to server with minimal code.

See the following minimal example (from the manual) on how to use the serialization APIs.  The [format](http://haxe.org/manual/std-serialization-format.html) is string based and specified.

```
import haxe.Serializer;
import haxe.Unserializer;

class Main {
  static function main() {
    var serializer = new Serializer();
    serializer.serialize("foo");
    serializer.serialize(12);
    var s = serializer.toString();
    trace(s); // y3:fooi12

    var unserializer = new Unserializer(s);
    trace(unserializer.unserialize()); // foo
    trace(unserializer.unserialize()); // 12
  }
}
```

Finally, you could also use other serialization formats like JSON (with `haxe.Json.stringify/parse`) or XML, but they wouldn't be so convenient if you're dealing with enums, class instances or other data not fully supported by these formats.

Comment: The problem is that I do not understand the chat example at all. The code is unreadable for me...but I decide to give up, thanks  anyway !

Comment: @SwordW, perhaps you'll find it easier to understand if you first try to build something more minimal, like a [simple remote call](http://old.haxe.org/doc/remoting/client_server) using remoting or, even simpler (or least, with less abstraction layers), a [dumb client/server message exchange with pure TCP](http://old.haxe.org/doc/neko/client_server) sockets.

Answer (score 1):

You could use JSON

You can put this in your openFL project (client):

```
var myData = [1,2,3,4,5];

var http = new haxe.Http("server.php");
http.addParameter("myData", haxe.Json.stringify(myData));
http.onData = function(resultData) {
    trace('the data is send to server, this is the response:' + resultData);
}
http.request(true);
```

If you have a *server.php* file, you can access the data like this:
`$myData = json_decode($_POST["myData"]);`

If the server returns Json data which needs to be read in the client, then in Haxe you need to do `haxe.Json.parse(resultData)`;